# Excel VBA range.find doesn't return the first appearance?

Tags: excel, vba, find

I have the following values in a worksheet:

```
A1:  apple
B1:  orange
C1:  pear
D1:  apple pie
E1:  papaya
F1:  blueberry
G1:  apple
```

My code:

```
t=rows(1).find("apple").column
```

Why does my code return the t as 7 instead of 1?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks Vasily for tidying up my post, which is my first one here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your coding makes the search *after* cell **A1**.  There are many ways to get the search to *include* **A1**.  Here is one:

```
Sub durals()
    Dim r As Range, r2 As Range
    Dim t As Long

    Set r = Range("1:1")
    Set r2 = r(1, Columns.Count)

    t = r.Find(What:="apple", After:=r2).Column
    MsgBox t
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks James.  I'm a newbie in VBA and is still in the learning stage.  May I ask for your kind help to explain what this statement does:  `Set r2 = r(1, Columns.Count)`

Comment: But, why does my code return correctly 1 if the value in G1 is not "apple"?

Comment: @Ken  Your code starts with **B1** and moves to the right.  Thus it finds the value in **G1** if it there.  If there is nothing good in **G1**, your code *wraps-around* at the end of the row and finally examines **A1**